# NameError: name 'Address' is not defined (when using python shell), but it is in models.py

Tags: python, django, shell, django-models, pycharm

I am trying to access all objects from a class Address, but I have no idea why I get NameError: name 'Address' is not defined when Address is right there in models.py.

Obviously I have run 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' (more than once).

Has anyone got any idea of why this happens?

[image]

Of course, if you need me to post any other screenshot just let me know it, as at the moment I don't know what else to show...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import your model.

```
from homepage.models import Address
Address.objects.all()
```